# How can I get the facebook comment that was just created

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have a single fb comment plugin on my page. When someone posts a comment using it, is there a way to get the comment text back?

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: You can't do this with only a plugin.  You'll have to implement this using some additional code which will be made easier by the use of an SDK...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `FB.Event.subscribe` method in the Facebook Javascript SDK. There is an event called `comment.create` and with this code you can find the new comment:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(post) {
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT text, post_fbid FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url = "' + post.href + '")'
    }, function(comments) {
        /* Iterate through the all comments for this url */
        for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
            /* Find the created comment text by its ID */
            if (comments[i].post_fbid == post.commentID) alert(comments[i].text);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Facebook's FQL like this: `SELECT text FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'YOUR_COMMENT_URL')`

Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).